# Get object value using dynamic key in jquery template

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

How to get the object value using dynamic key in jquery template.

Ordinary Script  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/zsc7rbLL/)

```
var viewModel = {
    "prop1": "a",
    "prop2": "b",
    "prop3": "c",
    "prop4": "d"
};
for (var dk = 1; dk <= 4; dk++){
    var elemName = "prop" + dk;
    jQuery("#result").append(viewModel[elemName]);
}
```

in the above script I get the key value dynamically and it works correctly.

In jquery template [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/rpMsM/81/)

```
{{each(prop, val) myObj}}
      <li><span>${prop}</span> - <span>${val}</span></li>
{{/each}}
```

how to get the "myObj" key as dynamic.

I use

```
${DT = "myObj"}
{{each(prop, val) DT}}
      <li><span>${prop}</span> - <span>${val}</span></li>
{{/each}}
```

but its not working.

Comment: ${DT = "myObj"} here DT will be a string but not an object... you have to ${DT = myObj} then it's fine